# Murder on the Fairway

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

A body has been found at the Green Estates Fairway.  Next to the body was a bloody golf club which was later confirmed by the medical examiner to be the murder weapon.  Thankfully, only ten men besides the victim had been golfing that day.  The police interviewed each man and asked:

1. How did you know the victim?
2. Did you have any reason to harm the victim?
3. What reasons might someone else have harmed the victim?
4. What was your final score after 18 holes that day?

After the interview the policeman asked each suspect to fill out a form containing their name, address, telephone number, and time and date of the preliminary interview conducted, so the police could follow up if necessary.  After interviewing all ten men, the police made an arrest and the man confessed to the crime.  How did the police know the culprit?

Hints:

1. > Did the police have an suspicion of who committed the crime before the interviews?
   > **No.**
2. > Did the police search the men's golf clubs for a matching set or missing club?
   > **No.**
3. > Was the club personalized in a way that gave police a lead?
   > **No.**

Big Hint:

4. > Was there something else unique about the club that led police to their conclusion?
   > **Yes.**

Comment: Was the murder weapon rot13(yrsg-unaqrq)?

Comment: Absolutely!  I think you’ve got it!

Comment: But @GreenestLantern there are so many possibilities. The Club could be a specific Brand that was played by only one man. Club could be 1970s wooden club. Could be a Graphite shaft only that no one played.

Comment: @DEEM, certainly, but i think that considering another user has already gotten to the crux of the riddle, it can be solved using what’s left in the riddle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is:

> The club used as the murder weapon was left-handed. The police watched each man write his answers, and noticed only one was left-handed.